# architecture x86_64 error in c++

Tags: c++, x86-64

When I try to run this c++ code with g++ on a mac Im getting the following error. Can someone tell me what it means. I am new to programming. So any help will be greatly appreciated. I am trying to use abstract classes (Expr.cpp) and subclass (Binary.cpp) to do this.

I used g++ main.cpp to compile

error -

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
"Expr::Expr()", referenced from:
  stepexecution(double, double, double)in cc8Vni4M.o
 "Expr::setArg(double)", referenced from:
  stepexecution(double, double, double)in cc8Vni4M.o
"Expr::setRece(double)", referenced from:
  stepexecution(double, double, double)in cc8Vni4M.o
"Binary::sum()", referenced from:
  stepexecution(double, double, double)in cc8Vni4M.o
"Expr::Expr()", referenced from:
  Binary::Binary()in cc8Vni4M.o
 ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
 collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

code

main.cpp -

```
 #include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

void stepexecution(double x, double y, double z)
{
string STRING;
Expr ex;
Binary bi;
ifstream infile;
char ele1;
char ele2;
char rece;
double d = 7;
infile.open ("program.txt");
while(!infile.eof()) // To get you all the lines.
{
    getline(infile,STRING);
    int length = STRING.length();

        if(length>8)
        {
            rece = STRING.at(0);
            ele1 = STRING.at(4);
            ele2 = STRING.at(8);
            cout << ele1 << ele2;
            if(ele1=='x' && ele2=='y')
            {
                ex.setArg(x);
                ex.setRece(y);
                double a = bi.sum();
                cout << a;
            }

        }


}
infile.close();
}

int main()
{
char c;
int t = 0;
double x = 10;
double y = 0;
double z = 0;
while(t==0)
{
    cout << "Please enter a command:";
    cin >> c;
    if(c=='r')
    {
        x=0;
        y=0;
        z=0;
    }
    if(c=='x')
    {
        cout << "Please enter the value of x:";
        cin >> x;
    }
    if(c=='y')
    {
        cout << "Please enter the value of x:";
        cin >> y;
    }
    if(c=='z')
    {
        cout << "Please enter the value of x:";
        cin >> z;
    }
    if(c=='s')
    {
        stepexecution(x,y,z);
    }
    if(c=='q')
    {
        exit(0);
    }
}

}
```

Expr.cpp -

```
#include "Expr.h"

void Expr::setRece(double x)
{
rece = x;
}
void Expr::setArg(double y)
{
arg = y;
}
//Constructor.
Expr::Expr()
{

}
```

Expr.h -

```
#ifndef ____Expr__
#define ____Expr__

#include <iostream>
#include "math.h"

using namespace std;

 class Expr {
public:
void setRece(double x);
void setArg(double y);
Expr();
protected:
double arg, rece;
};

#endif /* defined(____Expr__) */
```

Binary.cpp -

```
#include "Binary.h"

double Binary::sum()
{
return rece+arg;
}

double Binary::subt()
{
return rece-arg;
}

double Binary::mult()
{
return rece*arg;
}

double Binary::divi()
{
return rece/arg;
}

double Binary::exp()
{
return pow(rece,arg);
}
```

Binary.h -

```
#ifndef ____Binary__
#define ____Binary__
#include "Expr.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

 class Binary : public Expr
 {
public:
double sum();
double subt();
double mult();
double divi();
double exp();

};
#endif
```

Thanks for any help:)

Comment: Can you show make file or how did you compiled?

Answer (score 1):

This error means you have not linked your object files properly. All the object files must be linked to the final program.

If they are linked, then there are some functions which are not in any of the object files linked. Please link correct files.

to compile a file only to produce obj file use

```
  g++ -o binary.o -c binary.cpp
  g++ -o expr.o -c expr.cpp
```

Finally to link with main file use,

```
 g++ -o main main.cpp expr.o binary.o
```

Comment: nit: since this is c++, you should use `g++` for the link or some of the c++ libraries may not be linked.

Comment: So what obj files will I need to link here?